# How to access html form values from nested inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to validate input from this form:

```
        <form id = "mpath" name = "mpath" action = './../cgitest.cgi' method="POST" onsubmit = "return validateForm(this)">

            Total Time (in ms): <input type = "text" name = "ttime">
            Number of Cars (1-10): <input type = "text" name = "carnum">
            Initial Speed (fps): <input type = "text" name = "initspeed"><br>

            <!--extraRowTemplate will be repeated for every change in the accleration of the
                head car -->
            <p class = "extraRowTemplate" name = "extraRowTemplate">
                Change:
                <select name="change">
                <option value="acc">Acceleration</option>
                <option value="dec">Deceleration</option>
                </select>

                Start time: <input type = "text" name="starttime">
                End time: <input type = "text" name="endtime">
                Amount (in fps): <input type = "text" name="amount"><br>
            </p>

            <div id = 'container'></div>

            <a href="#" id = "addRow"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>Add Change</a><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Load Head Car">
        </form>
```

Using this function (I haven't written any of the actual validation):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(form){

            var tt = document.forms[0].ttime.value;
            var cn = document.forms[0].carnum.value;
            var is = document.forms[0].initspeed.value;
            var sta = form.elements[4].value;

            console.log(tt);
            console.log(cn);
            console.log(is);
            console.log(sta);


            if(tt == ""){
                alert("starttime must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

            //return false;
        }
    </script>
```

But when I try to submit values, it only finds the values for ttime, carnum, and initspeed, and not the value of starttime, endtime, or amount. Also, the value of change is always "acc", even if I set it to "deceleration".

For those wondering why I don't simply remove extraRowTemplate, I need to have those input options in a nested section because I have an option to duplicate them.

I've tried to pass the form as an argument to the function (as shown) as well as just use document.forms[0] to access it. Neither produce the correct result.

Also, when I remove the .value from the form.elements[4].value and set:

```
var sta = form.elements[4];
```

The console prints out:

```
 <input type = "text" name = "starttime">
```

Does anyone know how I can access the value of the nested inputs?

I suppose I should also say that the form works correctly in every other way, and when I send it to the cgitest.cgi, I can access all inputs. I just don't want to validate the inputs on the server side.

EDIT:

If instead of using an onsubmit function (validateForm in my case), I use an event listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var button = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]')

        button.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
          var ttime = document.querySelector('input[name=ttime]')
          var carnum = document.querySelector('input[name=carnum]')
          var initspeed = document.querySelector('input[name=initspeed]')
          var change = document.querySelector('select[name=change]')
          var starttime = document.querySelector('input[name=starttime]')
          var endtime = document.querySelector('input[name=endtime]')
          var amount = document.querySelector('input[name=amount]')

          console.info('ttime', ttime.value)
          console.info('carnum', carnum.value)
          console.info('initspeed', initspeed.value)
          console.info('change', change.value)
          console.info('starttime', starttime.value)
          console.info('endtime', endtime.value)
          console.info('amount', amount.value)

          event.preventDefault()
        })
    </script>
```

With the input ttime = 1, carnum = 2, initspeed = 3, change = "acc", starttime = 4, endtime = 5, amount = 6, I get the following console output:

```
(index):70 ttime 1
(index):71 carnum 2
(index):72 initspeed 3
(index):73 change acc
(index):74 starttime 
(index):75 endtime 
(index):76 amount
```

As can be seen, all values beyond initspeed (everything inside extraRowTemplate) are empty. Like I said before, they are not empty when sent to the form action url.

Comment: You may save some code by using HTML5's `required` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the `extraRowTemplate` and submit. If it's working, than you can try generating the elements inside with the different ids, because now you have duplicated items with no distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently accessing the elements in a bit of a roundabout way, using `document.forms[0].` Also I don't see any code to get the value of the `starttime` input. You are testing `tt` in the `if`, but that was assigned the value of `ttime`.

### document.querySelector

Might I suggest accessing the form elements by name directly, using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)? This method accepts a CSS selector and returns the first element that matches. Using a simple CSS3 selector we can select elements by name and assuming those names are unique on the page, we will get the right inputs. You could also use `form.querySelector` if the names are only unique within the form.

### Example

```
var myInput = document.querySelector('input[name=ttime]')
```

I find `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` (which gets all elements matching the CSS selector) very useful and use them all the time.

### Runnable code snippet

Run this snippet and press the form submit button to print the values of the inputs. Try it and see how it works.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]')

button.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
  var ttime = document.querySelector('input[name=ttime]')
  var carnum = document.querySelector('input[name=carnum]')
  var initspeed = document.querySelector('input[name=initspeed]')
  var change = document.querySelector('select[name=change]')
  var starttime = document.querySelector('input[name=starttime]')
  var endtime = document.querySelector('input[name=endtime]')
  var amount = document.querySelector('input[name=amount]')

  console.info('ttime', ttime.value)
  console.info('carnum', carnum.value)
  console.info('initspeed', initspeed.value)
  console.info('change', change.value)
  console.info('starttime', starttime.value)
  console.info('endtime', endtime.value)
  console.info('amount', amount.value)
  
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form id = "mpath" name = "mpath" action = './../cgitest.cgi' method="POST" onsubmit = "return validateForm(this)">

            Total Time (in ms): <input type = "text" name = "ttime">
            Number of Cars (1-10): <input type = "text" name = "carnum">
            Initial Speed (fps): <input type = "text" name = "initspeed"><br>

            <!--extraRowTemplate will be repeated for every change in the accleration of the
                head car -->
            <p class = "extraRowTemplate" name = "extraRowTemplate">
                Change:
                <select name="change">
                <option value="acc">Acceleration</option>
                <option value="dec">Deceleration</option>
                </select>

                Start time: <input type = "text" name="starttime">
                End time: <input type = "text" name="endtime">
                Amount (in fps): <input type = "text" name="amount"><br>
            </p>

            <div id = 'container'></div>

            <a href="#" id = "addRow"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>Add Change</a><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Load Head Car">
        </form>
```

Comment: I used querySelector and I still have a few problems:

Comment: Sorry, I clicked enter too soon. 
I used querySelector and I still have a few problems: When I simply put the code you provided on my page, the console does print the values of all the inputs whenever I click submit. However, when I use them in the validateForm function, the values of the nested inputs are still not given (while ttime, carnum, and initspeed are). I need to have to have them in the validateForm function because I don't want the form action to occur if the input is invalid.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to add a more complete example of the actual code that is not working for you could help. As it stands I can't really understand what the issue is.

Comment: I edited my question and code per your suggestions, but I'm getting the same problem that I originally had. I may just remove extraRowTemplate and duplicate the inputs fields another way.

Comment: @J.Page Actually your edit does not clarify... You say *As can be seen, all values beyond initspeed (everything inside extraRowTemplate) are empty.* But it cannot be seen because your code snippet is not runnable. [Use the insert code snippet button to make a runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)... and I'll bet it will show that actually, those values are printed just fine. BTW, please upvote if an answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I can access the value of your "starttime" field in Firefox/Chrome/Opera using either

```
var sta = document.forms[0][4].value
```

or

```
var sta = document.forms[0].starttime.value
```

Comment: Neither option is working for me. I can only access the fields outside extraRowTemplate using that notation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was going wrong. In my css I set:

```
.extraRowTemplate {
     display: none;
}
```

which was preventing the input values from being sent. Once I removed this my problems went away. Setting "visibility : hidden" is a good alternative that allowed the values to be submitted and the template not visible.